# onload event after dynamic data populates element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a service that pulls data from my server and populates it into a container on the page. I'm trying to get an onload event to fire after the data has completely loaded (images and all) into the element. Here is an example:

```
<div id="DynamicContainer"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: "www.serverurl.com/service.ashx",
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            var e = document.getElementById("DynamicContainer");
            var $e = $(e);
            $e.hide();
            e.innerHTML = ""; // Clear contents
            e.onload = function() { // Set load event
                $e.show(); // (This isn't firing after the 'e.innerHTML = data' has completed loaded)
            };
            e.innerHTML = data; // The above "onload" event isn't firing after the contents have loaded.
        }
    });
</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply setting the innerHTML does not trigger a `load` event.

You need to do something like

`$e.trigger('load')` just before returning from your `success` function.

Comment: That makes total sense, thank you! Any suggestion on when how to trigger only after the element's images and contents have been downloaded?

Comment: Once you're inside the `success` function, `data` contains all the stuff you requested from the server. So I'm not sure what you're asking, because as long as you `trigger` after setting your content, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The `load` event is only supported by the following tags ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)):

- body
- frame
- frameset
- iframe
- img
- input[type="image"]
- link
- script
- style

So since `#DynamicContainer` isn't one of those, you'll need an ad hoc solution. Something like this should do the trick:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "www.serverurl.com/service.ashx",
  async: true,
  success: onSuccess
});


function onSuccess(data) {
  var $el = $('#DynamicContainer'), deferreds;

  $el.hide().html(data);
  deferreds = $el.find('img').map(getOnLoadDeferred);

  $.when.apply($, deferreds)
  .done(function() { $el.show(); });

  function getOnLoadDeferred() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    this.onload = function imgOnLoad() { deferred.resolve(); };

    return deferred;
  }
}
```

Basically you render the html response in a hidden `#DynamicContainer`, wait for each `img` to fire `load`, then show `#DynamicContainer`. Note, you might want to add some logic to handle the case where an image fails to load.